# LIKE statement not finding all in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a like statement that looks like this:

`AND ( CONCAT( arc_property_res.STREET_NUM, ' ', arc_property_res.STREET_NAME ) LIKE '%{$address}%'`

The `NUM` and `NAME` are in different columns. Currently this query works if I have a single input field and enter: `000 Street Dr` But once I try and do: `000 Street Drive` I get 0 results. Same thing happens for Rd, Blvd, Pk and a few others.

I have tried using only one wildcard `%` but still not finding things. Any help or thoughts are appreciated.

---

### **UPDATE**

I converted the table to use MyISAM so I can use full text searches. So now all matching queries works ie: Dr, Drive, Rd, Road etc...

My query now looks like this:

`AND ( MATCH(arc_property_res.STREET_NUM, arc_property_res.STREET_NAME) AGAINST('{$address}')`

In some scenarios the address I enter does not come up first. Notice the correct listing is there, it is just not first.

Example:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you post some sample data and what do you expect the result to be

Comment: Hm, first section here on % wildcard ( http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php ).. Anyway, using a `_` breaks the query. And once I split them up ( num and name ) the query doesn't work.

Comment: @Razh I would like for the output to find all Street Names that include Dr, Drive, Rd, Road. This is a result if I use just `Dr` in the search: http://cl.ly/image/0T1A1V190343 but if I was to search that same address as `3033 Old Stone Drive` nothing comes up.

Comment: an option is to try to take out the front '%' from '%{$address}%' so it will look like '{$address}%' then if you type 3033 old stone it should return old stone Dr or Drive depending on what is in the database. I have to say it is also return 3033 old stone Rd or Road in the same search if they exist in the db

Comment: Please remove the update on your question and add it as an answer below. This will help future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it is difficult to tell what exactly you have in STREET_NUM and STREET_NAME, but if it works for `000` and  `Street Dr` lets assume that's our values.

Now we know that

`'000' + ' ' +  'Street Dr' LIKE '%000 Street Dr%'` worked.

Why should it work for:

`'000' + ' ' +  'Street Dr' LIKE '%000 Street Drive%'` ? I don't think it should.

That's just how `LIKE` operator works.

To fix this, you will need to have full names for streets, drives, closes etc. in your database instead of Dr., St., Cl.

Comment: I guess then the question should be, is the `LIKE` operator the right choice? Should it be a `REGEXP` or something else? This is for a real estate website and most people would write Drive or Road along with others writing Rd and Dr. So I would need both searches to find the results.

Comment: You could try [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) if you're using MyISAM tables.

Comment: Well, this is a big question. REGEXP will not give you anything new here. One possible solution would be to just REMOVE 'Rd', 'Road', 'St', 'Street', etc endings before doing LIKE, as they usually don't store extra information. Another good option will be to have an example on your website of what users should type in address field.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't recommend removing the ending... In my city, `90th Street` and `90th Avenue` are two very different places, about 25 miles away from each other.  Instead you could maintain a [table of common abbreviations](http://www.semaphorecorp.com/cgi/abbrev.html), and then normalize the data as it is inserted by using this table to replace the abbreviation with the long version.... this would also allow you to handle common misspellings.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like the following:

```
AND CONCAT( arc_property_res.STREET_NUM, ' ', arc_property_res.STREET_NAME ) LIKE '%{$address}%'
OR '{$address}' LIKE CONCAT( '%', arc_property_res.STREET_NUM, ' ', arc_property_res.STREET_NAME, '%' )
```

Since "dr" is the first two characters of "drive" you shouldn't have a problem.  However, "rd" is not the first two characters of "road" and you would clearly have a problem there.  You might look at coming up with replacements or better yet, trying some type of full text search.